# Ошибка безопасности — почему не могу зайти на страницу?

Tags: php, .htaccess, безопасность, framework, cakephp

Есть сайт с **CMS croogo** написанный на `cake.php`. Добавил страницу написанную на php в корень сайта (пробовал с расширениями php,html,ctp), но обратиться ни к ней напрямую, ни ссылаясь с другой страницы не могу - получаю ошибку по безопасности:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
может быть дело в файле .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm index.php5
#AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
#Options ExecCGI  Includes  IncludesNOEXEC  IncludesNOEXEC  SymLinksIfOwnerMatch  Indexes -Indexes
#RewriteEngine On

#Options    FollowSymLinks
#RewriteRule    ^   index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

по ссылке app/webroot/ перебрасывает на еще один файл .htaccess следующего содержания

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

т.е. правило `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]` как раз блокирует доступ и нужно его удалить или дополнить - как решить?

Comment: может вы ознакомитесь как вообще функционирует фреймворк [tag:cakephp] прежде чем в корень сайта страницы различные добавлять?

Comment: ПРоверьте, включен ли у Вас `mod_rewrite`

Comment: @teran это к сожалению, очень долго будет - а мне всего лишь страничку нужно добавить. может быть вы подскажете, если вам не сложно и вы с ним хорошо знакомы?

Comment: @Вася, я сейчай устанавливаю его и попробую что-то создать. Работал с кейком 3.х

Comment: @Вася вам `Croogo CMS` должна помочь с добавлением странички, разве  нет?

Comment: @RomanKozin смысл пробовать создавать что-то в корне движка, который реализует MVC модель? у него в принципе там кроме `index.php` быть  ничего не должно

Comment: @teran да, проверил - `mod_rewrite` работает. что можно сделать дальше? Так сами статические страницы я могу создавать - мне же нужно `php` добавить с условиями

Comment: @Вася вам нужно не просто `php`-файл добавить. Вам нужно создать класс контроллера (`src\Controllers`)и реализовать неоходимый экшен (метод класса) с вашей логикой и условиями. Далее сопоставить URL маршрут (`configs\routes.php`) этому экшену и контроллеру. Затем создать представление `src\template\YourControllerName\ActionName.ctp` где вывести данные. Это классическая MVC-модель, реализуемая в [tag:CakePHP]

Comment: @teran спасибо. это самый простой способ?

Comment: @Вася это нормальный способ. Все остальное сродни снять с автомобиля двигатель, приделать с правой стороны ручку от мясорубки в качестве педали и посадить туда водителя у которого только левая нога

Comment: @teran понял. а такой костыль временный можете описать как сделать? а как только с контроллерами разберусь - передалаю

Comment: @Вася прописать `RewriteRule` в `.htaccess`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53308/discussion-between--and-teran).